# Is every path connecting two distinct points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ homotopic to one another?

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

I had a curious thought; given two distinct points $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $n\geq 2$, is every path connecting them,
$$\gamma : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^n \mbox{ such that } \gamma(0)=x, \gamma(1)=y, \gamma \mbox{ continuous} $$
homotopic to the straight line connecting them,
$$ \ell  : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^n \mbox{ such that } \ell(t)= (1-t)x + ty ?$$

In other words, given any such path $\gamma$, does there always exist a continuous mapping $H:[0,1]\times[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
$$ H(t,0)=\gamma(t), H(t,1)=\ell(t)? $$

My suspicion is that the answer is yes, since paths are essentially one dimensional subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. The only defective case I can imagine is one where the path forms a loop and self intersects. But I think the crucial step of the solution to that case is picking a point on the loop, and showing the path before that point is homotopic to a line segment, and same with the path after that point.

The issue is I don't have enough experience to prove this rigorously, and also I could be missing some simple counterexamples. Any ideas?

Comment: $H(t, s) = s \ell(t) + (1-s) \gamma(t)$.

Comment: Since $\mathbb R^n$ is contractible, then ALL paths in it are homotopic.

Comment: If you don't insist that the endpoints stay fixed through the homotopy it doesn't even matter that this is in $\mathbb{R}^n$. $H(t, s) = \gamma(t(1-2s))$ if $s \le 1/2$ and $H(t, s) = \ell(t(2s-1))$ if $s \ge 1/2$.